# Simple namespace not working

Tags: php, namespaces

I have this files in the same directory say ..

file1.php

```
<?php
namespace Cars;

class Model
{
public function hello()
{
return "Hello";
}
}
```

file2.php

```
<?php

$car = new \Cars\Model;
$car->hello();
```

When i run file1.php , I am getting a fatal error cannot find  Class 'Cars\Model' not found

Comment: Check this [PHPDOCS for namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).. Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to include file1.php in file2.php? Can't find anything else that could cause an error.

```
<?php
include 'file1.php';
$car = new \Cars\Model;
echo $car->hello();
```